# Laravel | Reuse Query Variable instead of query duplication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, reusability

I am trying to reuse a query variable, but looks like it takes the last assigned value not the original one, here's what I mean:

```
$categories = DB::table('invoice_detail')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(qty) as qty')
            ->where('loc_id', '=', $user->loc_id)
            ->join('items', 'invoice_detail.item_id', 'items.barcode')
            ->where('items.active', '1')
            ->join('categories', 'items.category_id', 'categories.id')
            ->addSelect('categories.name')
            ->groupBy('categories.name');
        dump($categories->get()); //It returns whole products, which is OK.
        $topCategories  = $categories->orderBy('qty', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
        dump($categories->get()); // It returns the top products, not the original value.
        $downCategories = $categories->orderBy('qty', 'ASC')->take(5)->get();
```

I want to reuse the `$categories` variable to get the `Top Products` and `Down Products` without query duplication.

But in the first dump, it returns whole products, which is OK, then after getting the `Top Products`, it returns the top products, not the original value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always use [`__clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) method to make a `copy` of certain object **if and only if that object has __clone method implemented**:

```
$topCategories= clone $categories;
$topCategories->orderBy('qty', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
$downCategories = clone $categories;
$downCategories->orderBy('qty', 'ASC')->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: yeah, it should